# d3 json - Color a state manually in a map

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js, mapping

Learning d3js, I am following a lot of tutorials. Now I was able to create a simple US map from a json file with the same color for all states.
I found a lot of tutorials to create choropleth maps, however I want to color only a single state in this map manually (Lets say Alabama, which is the first feature in the json file).

This ist the code so far:

```
        var w = 500;
        var h = 300;

        var svg = d3.select("body")
                    .append("svg")
                    .attr("width", w)
                    .attr("height",h);

        var projection = d3.geo.albersUsa().translate([w/2,h/2]).scale([500]);         
        var path = d3.geo.path().projection(projection);

        d3.json("us-states.json", function(json){

            svg.selectAll("path")
                .data(json.features)
                .enter()
                .append("path")
                .attr("d",path)
                .style("fill","teal");
        });
```

while the json has the following structure:

```
{"type":"FeatureCollection","features":
[{"type":"Feature","id":"01","properties":{"name":"Alabama"},"geometry":
{"type":"Polygon","coordinates":[[[-87.359296,35.00118],    [-85.606675,34.984749],[-85.431413,34.124869],[-85.184951,32.859696],...
```

I don't know where to start. Do I need a second d3.json function with only Alabama as a selected path or can I do it with the already existing d3.json function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can add something like this:

```
svg.selectAll("path")
.attr("fill", function(d) {
    if(d.id === '01'){
      return #COLOUR;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can color the path by its id

Something like this:

```
 g.selectAll("path")
    .data(topojson.feature(us, us.objects.states).features)
    .enter().append("path")
    .attr("d", path)
    .style("fill", function(d) {
      if (d.id == 22) {
        return "red";//on condition match
      }
    })
    .attr("class", "feature")
```

Working code [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/ZNHBdHtIR9SndEa3yhsP?p=preview)

Comment: Thank you very much. Both your answers helped a lot!

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer ! , really saved time for me , i have a question though , how would i make  say the same state bigger (as in area size )? 
thank you